# How in hql query select part of object?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql

I need tune query for performance. The tree of objects like:

```
classA {
 classB b;
 classC c;
.....}
```

I need select similar to SQL:

```
select a.field1, b.field2, c.field3, c.field4 from a left outer join b 
  on a.id=b.fk left outer join c on b.id=c.fk
```

I don't understand what kind of result will be returned, does it arrayList? Or query returns
all 3 objects?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Comment: One more thing, if i am getting you need, this query should be like..

select a.field1, b.field2, c.field3, c.field4 from ClassA a left outer join ClassB b on a.id=b.fk left outer join ClassC c on b.id=c.fk

Answer (score 2):

The result which would be returned by the query would be type of -

```
 List<Object[]>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use HQL I think you use hibernate. Provide mapping with relations (ManyToOne or OneToOne) to your objects:

```
class A {

    @ManyToOne
    pribvate B b;

    @OneToOne
    private C c;
}
```

Then use session methods to select your object A with hql query of criteria. Hibernate do all joins for you automatically. And it will return List of A.

Comment: Sometimes that is too much data coming back, which was the original posters question.  The solution is exactly as laid out by manurajhada which is called a scalar select.